# How to secure an array for user access in firebase firestore?

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

In my angular firebase application many users can login and edit one and the same data. For example let's say they are editing documentations to specific topics. For every day a new Report object will be generated, which inherits the different topics and documentations. My data is structured like that:

```js
export interface Report {
    date: Date;
    day: string;
    topics: Topic[];
}

export interface Topic {
    name: string;
    documentations: Documentation[];
}

export interface Documentation {
    userId: string;
    userName: string;
    documentation: string;
}
```

I want to store the report as one object without subcollections, so I can load all the data at once without having to make a lot of read requests to the API. Moreover my users are split up into groups so a report will only have a maximum of 4 documentations per topic and around 6 to 10 topics.

So every user is allowed to read the documentations of other users but should only be able to edit his own documentations.
As far as I know, it is not possible to secure the access to an array via Firestore Security Rules so my only Ipossibility would be to user cloud functions to secure my data. But i don't know, if that is the most efficient way or if a different data structure would suit my situation better.
So if I am right and I have to use cloud functions, how can I check, if the user only edited his documentations and all the other ones are unedited? Or should I try a different approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If each user can write their own piece of the document, the correct data model is not an array but a mapping of the UID of the author to documentation they wrote:

```
documentations: Map<String, Documentation>;
```

Since you now know the key of the data each user is allowed to modify, this also gets you closer to being able to secure it. I just think you may still get stuck as I'm not sure if you can write a rule that covers "for all users".

---

Data structure issues like this are typically easier to solve if you *do* put the user-specific data in a subcollection of the document.

That's probably how I'd model it, and then use a Cloud Function to aggregate the data from the subcollection back into the parent document to still meet your requirement of only needing to *read* a single document to get all user's contributions.

I'd still use the model I mentioned above here too though, as that ensures you can perform the aggregation with a single (idempotent) write, instead of having to first read the parent document to check if the user already contributed to it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it really helped me, but it raised one further question.

In my reports there is some additional data stored, which should be able to be edited by users (`reportName`, etc.). However, they should not be able to edit the tendances, which are saved in my reports. Is there a way to achieve this through security functions or do i have to create a cloud function?

Comment: It sounds like something that can be secured via rules, but it's hard to be certain without specific details. Instead of asking about the use-case, I recommend trying to implement it based on the documentation and questions that have been asked before, and posting back with an [MCVE](https://status.firebase.google.com/) if you get stuck. That gives us a much better chance of helping efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Cloud functions then you can simple read that document, check that array, compare the user UID and check if user is editing their doc only and then update the whole document back.

```js
exports.addMessage = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  const {uid} = context.auth
  const {updates, documentationId, reportId} = data

  // 1. Fetch document using reportId
  // 2. Read the documentations array
  // 3. Check if doc with that ID exists and if caller owns it
  // 4. If yes, update else return 403 - forbidden error 
});
```